# jquery checkbox checked and unchecked

Tags: javascript, .net

i need to write a javascript code that make the checkbox if checked view a textbox and if not checked the text box is invisable automatically **without** having a button to click on it to do that

```
<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#Checkbox').click(function(){
            var checked_status = this.checked;
            if(checked_status == true) {
                $('#txt').show();
            }
            else { $('#txt').hide();
            }
        }); </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt" style="display:none"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: is the script you used working or not?

Answer (score 6):

First: id in html elements and javascript are case sensitive:

```
#Checkbox ≠ #checkbox
```

Second, **change** event is better than **click** for a checkbox.

```
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
   var checked = this.is(":checked");
   if (checked) {
      $("#txt").show();
   }
});
```

Third, you should wait until your dom is loaded, by declaring your script in **$(document).ready**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#checkbox").change(function() {
      var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
      if (checked) {
         $("#txt").show();
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: what if i wanted to make the same thing in but in

Comment: if the value in the select should decide if #txt is visible or not, you can use change event, instead of checked you can use val() of the select.

Comment: yes that is what i did but it didnt work 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#selection").change(function () {
     var mySelect = document.myform.myselectbox;
</script>
<form action="#" id="myform">
Selection: <select id='selection' >
<option >sarah</option>
<option >mai</option>
<option >alaa</option>
<option >salma</option>
<option id="Other" >laila</option></select>
<input type="text" id="txta" style="display:none" />
     var selIndex = mySelect.selectedIndex;
    if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
        $('#txta').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#txta').hide();
    }
});
});

Comment: is there any unchecked keyword (":unchecked") exists like (":checked"). in my case unchecked event doesn't fire. ? anyone pls help, how to trigger a unchecked event, when a checkbox is checked first and then unchecked again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simpler to validate  whether the checkbox is checked or not:

```
$('#Checkbox').is(':checked')
$('#Checkbox').attr('checked')
```

Comment: How to capture the unchecked event ? in my case, if i uncheck the already checked checkbox, I want to make a tetxbox's value empty.Is this possible? Is there anything like this exist:  var unchecked = $(this).is(":unchecked");

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
  var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
  if (checked) {
     $("#txt").show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#checkbox").change(function () {
        if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")== true) {
            alert("Checked");
        }
        else if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")== false) {
            alert("unChecked");
        }
    });    
</script>
```